# GUI Tool for HBase Management

Tags: hbase

Are there any good GUI tools available for HBase? Like MySQL has workbench and Yog.

Comment: Try [HAdmin](https://hadmin.io/). There you can create/alter/remove tables and column families, view some usefull info about your cluster's regions and region server etc.

Comment: Sometimes you need to think ahead. This was a question posted 7 years ago, when HBase was not so popular. I developed a simple GUI tool for this purpose sometime before. Available here https://sourceforge.net/projects/hbasemanagergui/ . Its not a in-depth administrative tool , but the basic CRUD , some DDL actions is possible with it. Its not heavy and not web-app.

Comment: everything is outdated only this works also for windows https://github.com/Observe-secretly/HbaseGUI

Answer (score 3):

If you're on windows there's [Toad for Cloud](http://toadforcloud.com/index.jspa)

Comment: We recently released HRider a GUI tool for accessing HBASE we developed internally as an open source project https://github.com/NiceSystems/hrider

Answer (score 1):

Check out [HBaseXplorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hbaseexplorer/) & [HBaseXplorer git link](https://github.com/zaharije/hbase-gui-admin).Its a java desktop application for managing and exploring HBase database.

Comment: tried it. but its not easy for a put operation even., is there any other?